# session_status() funciona en PHP 7.1?

Tags: php

Buen día, tengo un archivo php que utiliza un if con una la función session_status, en mi antiguo hosting funcionaba todo a la perfección (PHP 7.1) pero en mi nuevo host no funciona el IF (PHP 7.1), ¿que puede hacer que no funcione mi código?

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start(); 
} 
else { 
    echo 'ya estas logueado'; 
}
```

Comment: Que quieres decir con que no funciona el IF? `session_status()` puede devolver 3 valores diferentes. Por otro lado has probado haciendo la comparación estricta? Intenta desarrollar un poco más lo que quieres hacer y lo que está sucediendo, falta contexto.

Comment: Me refiero que aunque se cumplan las condiciones para que no funcione el código dentro del IF se ejecuta igualo

Answer (score 0):

Si tenías un código en otro hosting, con la misma versión de PHP, podrías entonces descartar el problema de versión. También puedes mirar aquí https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-status.

Dentro de ese mismo link, comentan algunas validaciones que puedes hacer https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-status.php#123404, es muy posible que no tengas el `session_start()`.

Comment: Si pruebo el if en un archivo en blanco funciona perfecto, pero en el archivo donde debería ir me dice "Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/costasoj/public_html/index.php:8) in /home/costasoj/public_html/include/menu.php on line 4" cosa que en el otro hosting no pasaba

Comment: Probaste agregar antes `session_start();` (y/o validarlo)? Puede ser que `session.auto_start`no esté habilitado. Por lo que, lo primero que intentaría validar, es que la sesión esté inicializada.

Comment: Considera leer [answer], al momento tu respuesta son mayormente enlaces

Comment: Probé agregando el session_start y dejó de mostrar el problema, pero aún asi al iniciar sessión no se guardan ni se crean las variables de $_SESSION